# Does anybody know how to use methods from "NgMatchers" like "toBeAnInstanceOf" for testing Angular2 RC3 apps

Tags: angular

I am trying to use some Angular 2 specific matchers functions defined in '.../platform-browser/testing/matchers.d.ts' for testing like:

```
it('The contacts component should have a valid constructor', () => {
    expect(contacts).toBeAnInstanceOf(Contacts);
});
```

but when running the test the error **'.toBeAnInstanceOf is not a function'** appears.

Probably I am missing something. Does anybody has a functional example?

```
TypeError: testing_1.expect(...).toBeAnInstanceOf is not a function
at eval (http://localhost:8080/js/components/contacts.component.spec.js:20:48)
at Object.eval (http://localhost:8080/@angular/core/testing/testing.js:98:26)
at attemptAsync (http://localhost:8080/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1916:24)
at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8080/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1871:9)
at http://localhost:8080/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1898:16
at http://localhost:8080/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1842:9
at Object.eval (http://localhost:8080/@angular/core/testing/testing.js:110:17)
at attemptAsync (http://localhost:8080/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1916:24)
at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8080/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1871:9)
at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:8080/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1859:10)
```

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Since RC4: **import {expect} from "@angular/platform-browser/testing"** (and all from **NgMatchers** for Jasmine) are no longer publicly exported APIs. If it is necessary to use any specific "matchers" then create your own utils instead.

Comment: What happens now is : testing_1.expect is not a function